Socketio emit doesn't work inside a thread
The title. I have this code with Paramiko and Flask Socket.io and the thread is not emitting the message:
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send
import paramiko
import threading

app = Flask(name)
sock = SocketIO(app)
shell = None


def ssh_connect():
    print("[DEBUG]: Starting SSH...")
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect("localhost", port=22, username="", password="")
    global shell
    shell = ssh.invoke_shell()

    while True:
        if shell.recv_ready():
            output = shell.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            print(output)
            sock.emit('output', output) #doesn't work
    ssh.close()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@sock.on('command')
def handleCommand(cmd):
    global shell
    shell.send(cmd['command'] + '\n')
    #sock.emit('output', output)

@sock.on('start')
def start(st):
    threading.Thread(target=ssh_connect).start()
    #sock.emit('output', output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("[DEBUG]: Starting server...")
    sock.run(app)

I tried using start_background_task and the same happens.
Also is not a problem with the client because it works in the other functions.
